# CaseStudy in Bugzilla

Tags: mysql, apache, bugzilla

I wish to conduct a case study in bugzilla, where I would like to ideally find out some statistics such as

1. The number of Memory Leaks
2. The percentage of bugs which are performance bugs
3. The percentage of semantic bugs

How can I search through the bugzilla database for softwares such as apache http server or mysql database server to generate such statistics. I would like an idea of how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out and am going to show my approach here. It's more or less a manual process. Hopefully this helps others as well who might be doing case-studies:

1. Selecting the bugs:

I went to bugs.mysql.com and searched for all bugs which were marked as resolved and fixed. Unfortunately, for mysql you cannot select specific components. I filtered out a random time range (2013-2014). And saved all of these in excel file(csv)

2. Classifying and filtering the bugs:

I manually went through the bugs, I skipped the ones which I could see clearly belonged to the documentation component, installation, compilation failure, or required restarts.

Then I read the report, and checked if the report actually suggested a bug fix, and if the bugfix was semantic (i.e. change limits, add a condition check, make sure some if condition is correctly marked for an edge case etc. - most were along similar lines). I followed a similar process for performance, resource-leak (both cpu resources, and memory leak considered in this category), and concurrency bugs.